# Ventana modal con Bootstrap no se muestra

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap

Estoy intentando mostrar una ventana modal cuando finalice un proceso después de presionar un botón pero lo único que hace es recargar la página otra vez, este es mi código:

**index.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' media="screen" />
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function ShowPopup(title, body) {
       $("#Popup .modal-title").html(title);
       $("#Popup .modal-body").html(body);
       $("#Popup").modal("show");
   }
```

```
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="auto-style2">
     <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="#">Titulo</a>
        </li>
         <asp:label ID="Menu" class="breadcrumb-item active" runat="server"></asp:label> 
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"></li>
     </ol>
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" Width="632px"  CssClass="auto-style3" Enabled="true" EnableTheming="True" />
        <br />     
        <asp:Button ID="btnvisualizarArchivo" cssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Visualizar" OnClick="visualizarArchivo_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCargarArchivo" cssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Cargar" OnClick="CargarArchivo_Click" OnClientClick="postback false" />


        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="Popup" class="modal fade" style="display:none">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">

            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>     
    </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>


        <div>
        <br />          
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:hidden">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdEjemplo" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" Width="860px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdEjemplo_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="4" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed small-top-margin" >
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-header" BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="White" Font-Size="small" />
            <PagerSettings FirstPageText="" LastPageText="" PageButtonCount="4" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" Font-Size="Small" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
        </asp:GridView>
         </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
              </div>   
        </div>
```

**index.cs**
Este el código que llamo en el botón que realiza el proceso y que cuando termine debería mostrar el popup

```
public void executeSP()
{
    SqlDataReader dataReader;
    string message = "";
    try
    {
      string constr =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Process_MenuWEB", con);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandTimeout = 3600;

            SqlParameter parameter1 = command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            parameter1.Value = idUpload.ToString();

            SqlParameter parameter2 = command.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            parameter2.Value = Session["UserId"].ToString();

            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                message = message +  dataReader["Observation"].ToString() + "//n";
            }

            string title = "Resultado de la transacción";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + title + "', '" + message + "');", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogging(ex);
    }
}
```

Estuve leyendo algunas soluciones y alguna de ellas era agregar un UpdatePanel para evitar que la página se recargue de nuevo pero aún así sigue sin funcionar, ¿Qué método podría usar para mostrar el Popup ?